# Can Alexa turn on and off individual outlets and switches?

Tags: alexa

I'm looking to buy an Alexa just had a few questions.

If I have multiple smart plugs and light switches can I ask Alexa to turn one on particular such as an example `Alexa turn on vanity light` and only the vanity light will turn on but on the same system can I have another outlet and say turn on plant lights and only turn on the plant light
And can I ask Alexa to turn on the overhead light?

And is there a way to turn them on at all the same time with one command?

Can you manually turn on switches that are connected to Alex?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can individually name devices and control them independently of each other.

You can also create groups of devices and control the groups.

As for if you can manually turn sockets on/off this will depend on the manufacture.